# Can't add additional where queries in Ardent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, ardent

I'm having a problem using LaravelBook/Ardent. My logic is exclude the soft deleted rows in unique validation using the code:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'name'  => 'required|unique:paper_colors,name,deleted_at,NULL',
    'description' => 'required|between:2,255',
    'code' => 'required'
);
```

But when I run the `updateUniques` I'm still getting `The name has already been taken.` and this sql:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `paper_colors` where `name` = '4/0' and `id` <> '2'
```

I'm expecting the sql will be:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `paper_colors` where `name` = '4/0' and `id` <> '2' and `deleted_at` is null
```

Can someone help me to solve this. I'm stuck almost last night on this. Still can't figure it out how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Ardent is dropping the Laravel Validation feature: [Adding Additional Where Clauses](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique)

So my solution to overcome this bug is to add additional code under `LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent@buildUniqueExclusionRules` at line: `799`, but I didn't do that since I'm depending for their any updates in the future. So I just create a class that extend `LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent` and copy `buildUniqueExclusionRules` and modify it.

```
if (count($params)>2)
{
    $c = count($uniqueRules);
    for ($i=1; $i < count($params); $i++, $c++) { 
        $uniqueRules = array_add($uniqueRules, $c, $params[$i]);
    }
}
```